# UNNEST all fields in ga_session table (returning no records)

Tags: google-bigquery, record, zero, unnest

[Image to Bigquery UNNEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dg46.png)

> How can I unnest all fields in ga_sessions, the above is returning no records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `,UNNEST(abc)` try `LEFT JOIN UNNEST(abc)`

Using LEFT JOIN with UNNEST instead of CROSS JOIN (which is short cut'ed as comma) ensures that if repeated record (array) is empty it will not make empty the whole row